# Load Component Only once in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-router, react-hooks

So I have a React App
And it has 2 pages
Lets say 1st one is Home and 2nd one is My Portfolio Section
And My Portfolio Section has 2 functional components in it

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <h1>Home Screen</h1>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Portfolio Section

```
import React from 'react'
import Projects from '../components/Projects'
import Testimonials from '../components/Testimonials'
const Portfolio = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    <Projects/>
    <Testimonials/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Portfolio
```

When I visit Home , Portfolio everything loads fine but when I re-visit them again they again reload each and everytime

I don't want the **Projects** component in the Portfolio Section to load more than once
I want it to load only once on the Startup / when launching the site even before visiting the Portfolio section ( that is in background ) as it has large files that will take time to load and stay the same until user refreshes the page voluntarily .

The  component has some 3d models in it which uses three.js
So it is not a static site
It will have its own animation
But the entire component loading each time the page visited will take a lot of time

But the **Testimonials** component will change dynamically

So in 2 of the components I want one to stay the same without reloading
And other to change dynamically

How can I make a component load only once
Any suggestion would help me
I saw UseMemo but I don't know whether that would help me
If so can someone explain how to use it in my case

Answer (score 0):

When the relevant component (`Projects`) is first rendered, create the animation, and cache it in a variable that is external to the component (`let animation` in the example). Whenever the component is mounted, get the the animation from the external variable, and start it. And when it's unmounted stop the animation.

**Note:** This would work if you only render a single instance of the component. If you're going to render multiple instances, you'll need to come up with a system to cache an rerender an animation for each instance - probably some kind of a Map with a constant id for each instance.

**Example** - toggle the pages, and the animation would continue

```js
const { Fragment, useState, useEffect, useRef } = React

let animation

const Projects = () => {
  const container = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {    
    if(!animation) {
      animation = createAnimation()
    }
    
    container.current.appendChild(animation.domElement)
    
    animation.start()
    
    return () => animation.stop()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div ref={container} /> 
  )
}

const Home = () => (
  <span>Home Screen</span>
)

const Portfolio = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <span>Portfolio</span>
    <Projects />
  </Fragment>
)

const App = () => {
  const [showPortfolio, setShowPortfolio] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <button 
        onClick={() => setShowPortfolio(!showPortfolio)}>
        Toggle
      </button>
      
      {showPortfolio ? <Portfolio /> : <Home />}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
)

function createAnimation() {
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
  });
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  camera.position.z = 5;

  let requestId;

  const animate = () => {
    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };

  return {
    start: animate,
    stop: () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestId),
    domElement: renderer.domElement
  }
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r126/three.min.js" integrity="sha512-n8IpKWzDnBOcBhRlHirMZOUvEq2bLRMuJGjuVqbzUJwtTsgwOgK5aS0c1JA647XWYfqvXve8k3PtZdzpipFjgg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me out , Here you just toggled between 2 components , can this be used when we route to seperate pages . Like if I click one student name in Home page it will route to that Student Portfolio where it will have the same static 3d model Projects and Different Testimonials , How can this done while routing where pages are refreshed each time .

Comment: The 3d model is not saved on a page, but as a variable. You can create a singleton in a file, and save the models to it, and import it to both components. Pages (and routes) are components, so it shouldn't matter if it's using routing or not. Try it.